# Can songbirds mimic car alarm sounds?

Tags: zoology, ornithology

A silly question. A few days ago I observed a very vocal bird with impressive vocal variety. It was rapidly switching from one tune to the next. After sometime I realized that the bird might be mimicking the 6-8 tone car alarm (the one that rapidly changes). Is this my imagination, or are birds really know to mimic/compete with car alarms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would be amazed at the vocal abilities of the [lyrebird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyrebird).  A car alarm is easy for them; they can mimic much more complicated sounds.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjE0Kdfos4Y)'s a snippet from a David Attenborough BBC documentary on YouTube (which includes the car alarm example, among others).  They are so skilled, it's hard not to think this video is fake.

Comment: Thanks, that bird does imitate car alarm, but I was really surprised at the chainsaw sound